# In Joomla PHP page change a resourse from a directory to a remote website

Tags: php, joomla

I have a Joomla 3.4.8 site that sells downloads. My shopping cart is a plugin. I would like to point the shopping cart plugin to a different server where my downloads will be served from. This will take the load off of my website server. I have found a function that points to the download file directory, but am unsure how alter it because it seems to have some custom Joomla code. I realize that this function example just shows the files size, but if I can figure out how to alter this part, I can also alter the other PHP files referencing this directory `/media/com_eshop/files/`.

So I basically need to change

```
/media/com_eshop/files/
```

to

```
http://example.com
```

somehow.

```
/**
 *
 * Function to display list downloads for user
 * @param string $tpl
 */
function _displayDownloads($tpl)
{
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    if ($user->id)
    {
        $tax = new EshopTax(EshopHelper::getConfig());
        $currency = new EshopCurrency();
        $downloads = $this->get('Downloads');
        foreach ($downloads as $download)
        {
            $size = filesize(JPATH_SITE.'/media/com_eshop/files/'.$download->filename);
            $i = 0;
            $suffix = array(
                'B',
                'KB',
                'MB',
                'GB',
                'TB',
                'PB',
                'EB',
                'ZB',
                'YB'
            );
            while (($size / 1024) > 1)
            {
                $size = $size / 1024;
                $i++;
            }
            $download->size = round(substr($size, 0, strpos($size, '.') + 4), 2) . $suffix[$i];
        }
        $this->downloads = $downloads;
        // Warning message
        $session = JFactory::getSession();
        if ($session->get('warning'))
        {
            $this->warning = $session->get('warning');
            $session->clear('warning');
        }
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
    else
    {
        $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
        $uri = JUri::getInstance();
        $mainframe->redirect('index.php?option=com_users&view=login&return=' . base64_encode($uri->toString()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well JPATH_SITE.'/media/com_eshop/files/' means http://example.com/media/com_eshop/files

JPATH_SITE is The path to the installed Joomla site.

so I think that you can basically change this line : JPATH_SITE.'/media/com_eshop/files/'

to 'http://downloads.example.com/files/'

or something.
Be aware that i didn't test this but I think that it'll work